# When to declare a datepicker in Meteor, startup or rendered

Tags: meteor

I am a newbie in Meteor and trying to make a form-maker (mforms):
https://github.com/miguelalarcos/mforms

I have a question about when I should declare that an input is a datepicker:

```
$('.'+form_name+'_attr_date').datepicker(format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', autoclose:true)
```

I don't know if the better place is at Meteor.startup or maybe at template.rendered.
The same for declaring the function source of a typeahead input text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put it inside template.rendered because it will only run when the user uses that template.  If you put it in startup it will run for every user -- even if that user never uses the template with that date picker.  In addition, code inside of startup runs on server and client.  It doesn't make sense to run this code on the server.

**From the documentation:**

[rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered)

```
This callback is called once when an instance of Template.myTemplate is rendered into DOM nodes and put into the document for the first time, and again each time any part of the template is re-rendered.
```

[startup](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_startup)

```
Run code when a client or a server starts.

On a server, the function will run as soon as the server process is finished starting.
On a client, the function will run as soon as the DOM is ready.
```